# Unable to Remove products from wishlist

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.6

I want to remove product from wishlist in product listing page(default/template/wishlist/item/column/image.php).

I have seen the remove url function in wishlist page `$this->getItemRemoveUrl($item)` . but it doesn’t work in image.php.
Even i tried,

```
echo Mage::helper(‘wishlist’)->getRemoveUrl($_product)
```

it gives URL but not showing parameters.

eg:-

```
domain.com/wishlist/index/remove (not working)
domain.com/wishlist/index/remove/item/3 (actual)
```

So how can i solve this

Comment: By default user of your sites have option to create wishlist and delete products from wishlist. I think some problem in your magento ecommerce. Some miscoding are created from you or by your developer. Please check that. If you find any coding problem then solve it or try to compare with fresh magento I think its helpful for you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this function should work for you

```
Mage::helper('wishlist')->getRemoveUrl($_product)
```

Answer (score 3):

Please compare your xml file with the magento default xml file

May be there is any `function` missing or commented

Also there is another possibility or error

in

```
helper('wishlist')->getRemoveUrl($_product)
```

may be `$_product` contains additional white spaces or symbols

please check it

Comment: magento's function generate this wrong url http://www.example.com/wishlist/index/remove but that should be like this
http://www.example.com/wishlist/index/remove/item/{product_id}

but if i manually create url with existing product id and hit url then it says page not found

Comment: @vipin Kumar check weather any additional concatenation to **$_product** by **.** (dot)

Answer (score 1):

Using the `getModel` you can delete the wishlist product 
as below

```
Mage::getModel('wishlist/item')->load($id)->delete();
```

Comment: no these are wrong you are posting to delete product through model but am asking about magento's api doesn't render remove url

Comment: I dont think there is any magento's api for removing the wishlist product I will check it and will get back to you